# Django Message format error on Reverse Redirect

Tags: django, message

I am getting a formatting error with messages when I use a redirect like the one below.

```
msg = 'Guest Users are not Authorized.'
messages.warning ( request, msg )

return redirect ( reverse ( 'page:index', kwargs = { 'slug': slug } ) )
```

or

```
return redirect ( 'page:index', slug = a.slug  )
```

[image]

Messages are fine with the below example when I just do a return render().

```
msg = '{} has been Updated.'.format ( a.abrev )
messages.success ( request, msg )

return render ( request, template, context )
```

[image]

Is there something about redirects and messages?

I am using Django 2.0, Cookiecutter and Foundation.

Thank you.